# Twoway connection between two swing Documents

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a simple Java swing application. I have **two JTextPanes**. On the first one I can write a html code and on the second one I see the appearience defined by the code. My goal is to provide `two-way connection` between this textpanes, so that if I type some characters in one pane, I see the changes in the second pane. And that must work in two ways: I can type in both code pane and content pane and changes should be automatically applied to the other pane.

I have tried to use two `DocumentListener` objects to handle `DocumentEvents`, but if I change the content of one pane it fires an event and second pane is modifing and also fires an event and this is repeating all the time, so it's not a good way. Setting the same document instance on both text panes also doesn't work.

What should I do? Here is my code. I have an exception IllegalStateException now.

```
public class TestEditor extends JFrame {

public TestEditor(){
    createConnection();
    createGUI();
}
private void createGUI(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JScrollPane scroll1=new JScrollPane(text);
    JScrollPane scroll2=new JScrollPane(html);
    JSplitPane split=new JSplitPane();
    split.setLeftComponent(scroll1);
    split.setRightComponent(scroll2);
    split.setDividerLocation(0.5);
    split.setResizeWeight(0.5);
    getContentPane().add(split);
    setTitle("Test");
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,300));
    pack();
}
private void createConnection(){
    text=new JTextPane();
    html=new JTextPane();
    html.setContentType("text/html");
    html.getStyledDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            text.setText(html.getText());
        }
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            text.setText(html.getText());            
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            text.setText(html.getText());
        }
    });
    text.getStyledDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            html.setText(text.getText());
        }
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            html.setText(text.getText());
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            html.setText(text.getText());
        }
    });
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new TestEditor().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private JTextPane text;
private JTextPane html;
```

}

Comment: den where is your code.

Comment: You need some way to detect when the change is coming from the other `DocumentListener`, so you can "ignore" any updates.  This is basically a manual process of setting some kind of flag which when the `DocumentListener` is notified, it can ignore any changes

Comment: Add the Listener when one field gets focus and remove it again when it loses focus.

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer. Your hint was very useful, it works fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;

public final class TwoWayEditor extends JFrame{

    private JTextPane  textPane;
    private JTextPane  viewPane;    
    private JSplitPane contentPane;
    private static DocumentListener textPaneDocumentListener;
    private static DocumentListener viewPaneDocumentListener;

    @Override
    protected void frameInit(){
        super.frameInit();      
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.selfInitialize();
    }

    private void selfInitialize(){  

        textPane    = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/plain");
        textPane.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){ textPane.getStyledDocument().addDocumentListener(textPaneDocumentListener);}
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){ textPane.getStyledDocument().removeDocumentListener(textPaneDocumentListener); }
        });


        viewPane    = new JTextPane();
        viewPane.setContentType("text/html");       
        viewPane.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){viewPane.getStyledDocument().addDocumentListener(viewPaneDocumentListener);}
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){viewPane.getStyledDocument().removeDocumentListener(viewPaneDocumentListener);}
        });

        viewPaneDocumentListener = new DocumentListener(){
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
                textPane.setText(viewPane.getText());
            }
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){ textPane.setText(viewPane.getText());}
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){ textPane.setText(viewPane.getText());}
        };
        textPaneDocumentListener = new DocumentListener(){
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
                viewPane.setText(textPane.getText());
            }
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){ viewPane.setText(textPane.getText()); }
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){ viewPane.setText(textPane.getText()); }
        };

        contentPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,true,textPane,viewPane);
        this.setContentPane(contentPane);

        contentPane.setDividerLocation(this.getWidth()/2);
    }

    public static void main(final String [] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{ TwoWayEditor editor = new TwoWayEditor(); });
    }
}
```

Comment: The HTML used by the JTextPane is HTML 3.2.  Otherwise, this is an interesting solution.